# Помогите скачать пакет

Tags: bash, kali-linux

Я пытаюсь скачать пакет pip:
sudo apt-get install python-pip
Но после этого выдает ошибку :
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Что делать?
Какие пакеты нужно удалить?

Comment: Попробуйте, что советуют там: https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/387795.

Comment: Не открывайте, пожалуйста, сто-пятьсот вопросов.  Отредактируйте уже имеющийся.

Answer (score 1):

А попробуйте установщиком Aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude install python-pip
```